# how to column comments in sequelize models mysql in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

how to column comments in sequelize models mysql in nodejs?

This is my model code.

```
        "use strict";

    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      var Model = sequelize.define("Market_Details", {
        bookingDate: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false },
        bookingType: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
          comment: "S- SINGLE, M- MULTIPLE"
        }
});
      Model.prototype.toWeb = function(pw) {
        let json = this.toJSON();
        return json;
      };

      return Model;
    };
```

I write comment could not update the comment in column.
Only create in table and column name.

how to solve this problem,help me.

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

This should work because I tried your code it worked for me. I believe bthe error is as a result of not closing brackets

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 var Model = sequelize.define("Market_Details", {
 bookingDate: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false },
 bookingType: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    comment: "my comment"
  },
})
 Model.prototype.toWeb = function(pw) {
    let json = this.toJSON();
    return json;
  };

  return Model;
};
```

Comment: Sorry, This is not working comments not added in bookingType columns

Comment: That's strange because even, in sequelize docs that's the procedure for adding comments to a table

Comment: Are u querying for the comments or what? Like expecting the comment to be visible with query data